# Where does Java store the data?

Tags: java, oop, jar

I am new to Java/ OOP and just learning the basics. I have a basic doubt.

Say I have developed an application, created executable file and distributed to my client. All that the customer knows is to click on that application, it gets launched and he uses it.

But as a developer, say I have some stuff going on inside such as new object creation, methods, etc. So if the customer uses that application and clicks on an icon "Create new product", the application is actually creating a new object using constructor. Similarly when the customer enters some other buttons, at the backend some methods are called.

More importantly, I may have some data file which has existing data of some products and as the client creates new products, the information of new products is added to this data file.

My doubt is where is this data stored in Java? Say the client creates 1000 or million products by using this application, where is all this information stored. Does the data file gets updated? Can the data in source file get changed? Or is it like, the client needs to have some external storage place like database where I link the existing data file.

I am unable to frame the question properly as I myself am not clear about this. I am totally new to Java/OOP. My basic doubt is when I finish learning Java and develop applications to be used by client, where will the data that the client creates using the application go?

Comment: Well, it depends how the application works. If you will always store/retrieve data from a file, then the data is stored in this file. If the operations are done against a database, then in a database. If none of these, then in memory. Since we don't know how the app is built, we cannot provide further info.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza:  In all reality that could be framed as an answer - the main point is that it's either a backing store of some kind or in memory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Constructor create object in memory only, and once your app is closed or pc shutdown your data will be lost,

store data in a file is useful to store application settings, you have to use an xml or a properties file.

If you want to store your business or other data in a database, you have to learn the java persistence API ,some relational database and some persistence provider and your object (class) must implements serializable interface.

if you need to store and manage a very huge data (BIG DATA) you have to use NoSQL database.